# Whoops, looks like an error occured. Phonegap Error

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, phonegap-build

I am trying to build an android app using HTML, CSS and Javascript (PHONEGAP). When I biult and install in my mobile, I found this error (Whoops, looks like an error occured). I tried many time but all the time I found this. It is ok in you Chrome Browser, but not working when I am installing it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8osLh.png)

I even tried by downloading the files direct from github and build, but got the same error everytime.

Please anyone help me...

==========================index.html======================

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <!-- This is a wide open CSP declaration. To lock this down for production, see below. -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />
    <!-- Good default declaration:
    * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
    * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
    * Disables use of eval() and inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
        * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        * Enable eval(): add 'unsafe-eval' to default-src
    * Create your own at http://cspisawesome.com
    -->
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: 'unsafe-inline' https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" /> -->


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <!-- Include the jQuery library -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />

    <title>Pizza Hut</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Pizza Hut</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening"> Connecting to Device </p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>

            <form>      
        <input type="hidden" name="name" id="name"value="" /><br>   
        <input type="hidden" name="mail" id="mail"value="" /><br>   
        <input type="hidden" name="mob" id="mob"value="" /><br> 

        <input type="hidden" name="ip" id="ip"value="" /><br>   
        <input type="hidden" name="longi" id="longi"value="" /><br> 
        <input type="hidden" name="lati" id="lati"value="" /><br>   



         <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="getData1()">
        </form>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>






    </body>

</html>
```

===========================Cordova.js=====================

```
if (window.cordova && !(window.cordova instanceof HTMLElement)) {
    throw new Error("cordova already defined");
}


var channel = require('cordova/channel');
var platform = require('cordova/platform');



var m_document_addEventListener = document.addEventListener;
var m_document_removeEventListener = document.removeEventListener;
var m_window_addEventListener = window.addEventListener;
var m_window_removeEventListener = window.removeEventListener;

var documentEventHandlers = {},
    windowEventHandlers = {};

document.addEventListener = function(evt, handler, capture) {
    var e = evt.toLowerCase();
    if (typeof documentEventHandlers[e] != 'undefined') {
        documentEventHandlers[e].subscribe(handler);
    } else {
        m_document_addEventListener.call(document, evt, handler, capture);
    }
};

window.addEventListener = function(evt, handler, capture) {
    var e = evt.toLowerCase();
    if (typeof windowEventHandlers[e] != 'undefined') {
        windowEventHandlers[e].subscribe(handler);
    } else {
        m_window_addEventListener.call(window, evt, handler, capture);
    }
};

document.removeEventListener = function(evt, handler, capture) {
    var e = evt.toLowerCase();
    // If unsubscribing from an event that is handled by a plugin
    if (typeof documentEventHandlers[e] != "undefined") {
        documentEventHandlers[e].unsubscribe(handler);
    } else {
        m_document_removeEventListener.call(document, evt, handler, capture);
    }
};

window.removeEventListener = function(evt, handler, capture) {
    var e = evt.toLowerCase();
    // If unsubscribing from an event that is handled by a plugin
    if (typeof windowEventHandlers[e] != "undefined") {
        windowEventHandlers[e].unsubscribe(handler);
    } else {
        m_window_removeEventListener.call(window, evt, handler, capture);
    }
};

function createEvent(type, data) {
    var event = document.createEvent('Events');
    event.initEvent(type, false, false);
    if (data) {
        for (var i in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                event[i] = data[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return event;
}


var cordova = {
    define:define,
    require:require,
    version:PLATFORM_VERSION_BUILD_LABEL,
    platformVersion:PLATFORM_VERSION_BUILD_LABEL,
    platformId:platform.id,

    addWindowEventHandler:function(event) {
        return (windowEventHandlers[event] = channel.create(event));
    },
    addStickyDocumentEventHandler:function(event) {
        return (documentEventHandlers[event] = channel.createSticky(event));
    },
    addDocumentEventHandler:function(event) {
        return (documentEventHandlers[event] = channel.create(event));
    },
    removeWindowEventHandler:function(event) {
        delete windowEventHandlers[event];
    },
    removeDocumentEventHandler:function(event) {
        delete documentEventHandlers[event];
    },
    /**
     * Retrieve original event handlers that were replaced by Cordova
     *
     * @return object
     */
    getOriginalHandlers: function() {
        return {'document': {'addEventListener': m_document_addEventListener, 'removeEventListener': m_document_removeEventListener},
        'window': {'addEventListener': m_window_addEventListener, 'removeEventListener': m_window_removeEventListener}};
    },

    fireDocumentEvent: function(type, data, bNoDetach) {
        var evt = createEvent(type, data);
        if (typeof documentEventHandlers[type] != 'undefined') {
            if( bNoDetach ) {
                documentEventHandlers[type].fire(evt);
            }
            else {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    // Fire deviceready on listeners that were registered before cordova.js was loaded.
                    if (type == 'deviceready') {
                        document.dispatchEvent(evt);
                    }
                    documentEventHandlers[type].fire(evt);
                }, 0);
            }
        } else {
            document.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }
    },
    fireWindowEvent: function(type, data) {
        var evt = createEvent(type,data);
        if (typeof windowEventHandlers[type] != 'undefined') {
            setTimeout(function() {
                windowEventHandlers[type].fire(evt);
            }, 0);
        } else {
            window.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }
    },


    callbackId: Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000000000),
    callbacks:  {},
    callbackStatus: {
        NO_RESULT: 0,
        OK: 1,
        CLASS_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION: 2,
        ILLEGAL_ACCESS_EXCEPTION: 3,
        INSTANTIATION_EXCEPTION: 4,
        MALFORMED_URL_EXCEPTION: 5,
        IO_EXCEPTION: 6,
        INVALID_ACTION: 7,
        JSON_EXCEPTION: 8,
        ERROR: 9
    },

    /**
     * Called by native code when returning successful result from an action.
     */
    callbackSuccess: function(callbackId, args) {
        cordova.callbackFromNative(callbackId, true, args.status, [args.message], args.keepCallback);
    },

    /**
     * Called by native code when returning error result from an action.
     */
    callbackError: function(callbackId, args) {
        // TODO: Deprecate callbackSuccess and callbackError in favour of callbackFromNative.
        // Derive success from status.
        cordova.callbackFromNative(callbackId, false, args.status, [args.message], args.keepCallback);
    },

    /**
     * Called by native code when returning the result from an action.
     */
    callbackFromNative: function(callbackId, isSuccess, status, args, keepCallback) {
        try {
            var callback = cordova.callbacks[callbackId];
            if (callback) {
                if (isSuccess && status == cordova.callbackStatus.OK) {
                    callback.success && callback.success.apply(null, args);
                } else if (!isSuccess) {
                    callback.fail && callback.fail.apply(null, args);
                }

                if (!keepCallback) {
                    delete cordova.callbacks[callbackId];
                }
            }
        }
        catch (err) {
            var msg = "Error in " + (isSuccess ? "Success" : "Error") + " callbackId: " + callbackId + " : " + err;
            console && console.log && console.log(msg);
            cordova.fireWindowEvent("cordovacallbackerror", { 'message': msg });
            throw err;
        }
    },
    addConstructor: function(func) {
        channel.onCordovaReady.subscribe(function() {
            try {
                func();
            } catch(e) {
                console.log("Failed to run constructor: " + e);
            }
        });
    }
};


module.exports = cordova;
```

==========================================================

Comment: Look at my index files

Comment: Please look at the question now. I have update it (added index file)

Comment: Please remove content security meta tag. and try again

Comment: #Krishna vrinsoft Sir, I did the above, but it not worked...

Comment: Can anyone help, please

Comment: A better error-message would help very much. Try to debug in Chrome to get further information. How to enable webview inspection see [here](https://gonzalo123.com/2014/08/04/debugging-android-cordovaphonegap-apps-with-chrome/). You can then see the console output.

Comment: Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Since this appears to be your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App?
Are you using the *Phonegap Desktop App*? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: Dear JesseMonroy650, thak you so much for your response.
Yes this is my first hybrid app. Yes I am using Phonegap Desktop App. I simply downloading the tempale of pohnegap form github, change the index.html and config.xml. compress the files and upload the files in http://build.phonegap.com. Every thing goes fine, but When I download the apk it does not work for me. and givs the above error every time.

Comment: I want to add only some text in index files and want to upload it on build.phonegap.com to convert it into apk. But I am unable to do this.

Comment: Hi JesseMonroy650!!! I am still having the same problem with phonegap, Can you please compile my app, it is only one HTML page which I Just want to user 5-10 Android phone.